# How to find in what Panel my button is placed in?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have some questions that are situated in distinct panels. I place `button` "Add" in every panel. This button is supposed to add additional textbox to panel. But I don't know what to write in `button_click`. What panel to choose?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `button.Parent` property?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Control.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null)
        return; //Some error/exception

    Panel parentPanel = button.Parent as Panel;
    if (parentPanel == null)
    {
        //Parent container is not panel
    }
    //Otherwise get the panel properties. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume all the "Add" buttons are subscribed to this same event.

The value of `sender` will be the particular "Add" button that was just clicked. Then you can cast the button's `Parent` to a `Panel`:

```
var button = (Button)sender;
var parentPanel = (Panel)button.Parent;
```

These two lines will be sufficient as long as

- You don't accidentally attach some other control other than a button to this event
- All the "Add" buttons are contained within a `Panel`.